# i need of id of that button clicked by the user before loading

Tags: javascript, ajax

i tried a couple of different methods like creating a function called check() which is called onclick which gave the id of the button. But i need that id to get the value of the button which the user has selected and pass it into a variable which is in another function that is called on load. the problem here is that the getelementbyid tag doesnt recognize the variable from check function since it is called on click while the function containing getelementbyid is called onload

code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';
echo '<response>';
$food=$_GET['food'];
//food=$_GET['food'];
// $choice=$_GET['choice'];
// echo "yes".$cold;

$foodarray=array('tuna','Bacon','beef');
if(in_array($food,$foodarray)) {
    echo "we do have".$food."!";
}
elseif(empty($food)) {
    echo "ENter a food";
}
else {
    echo "aint got ".$food;
}
echo'</response>';
?>
```

foodstore.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="foodstore.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body onload="process()">

       Type:
  <input type="radio" id="ge1" value="member" onclick=check() name="type">member
  <input type="radio" id="ge2" value="user" onclick=check() name="type">user

<div id="underInput"/></div>
</body>
</html>
```

foodstore.js

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();
var z="";
function createXmlHttpRequestObject(){
    var xmlHttp;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}

function check() {
    var yos=document.getElementsByName("type");
    var len=yos.length;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
        if(yos[i].checked) {
            z=yos[i].value;
        }
    }
    alert(z);
}

function process() {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4){
        food = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById(z).value);
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "foodstore.php?food="+food,true);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    } else{
        setTimeout('process()',1000);//cekaj 1s pa probaj opet
    }
}

function handleServerResponse(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){ 
        if(xmlHttp.status==200){
            var xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML; 
            root = xmlResponse.documentElement;
            message = root.firstChild.data;
            kat=document.getElementById("underInput");
            kat.innerHTML+= message;
            //setTimeout('process()', 1000);
        } else {
            alert('Someting went wrong !');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `function check(e){ alert(e.target.id);}`, but bind the click in js instead of html

Comment: i am totally a noob here could u clarify please?

Answer (score 0):

Pass `this` into function

```js
function check(el) {
  console.log(el.id, 'clicked')
}
```

```html
<label>
   <input type="radio" id="ge1" value="member" onclick=check(this) name="type">
   member
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" id="ge2" value="user" onclick=check(this) name="type">
    user
</label>
```

Comment: what does "console.log(el.id, 'clicked')" do?

Comment: did you run the snippet and click on the elements?

Comment: found the soltuion